# Deploy a project to Vercel just returns 404 - not found

Tags: reactjs, node.js, deployment, vercel

I'm facing an issue when uploading my project to Vercel. It's a training project, based on a Udemy course that was made thinking in Heroku deployment, but i'm trying to use Vercel in that place.

[My project basic structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr6x6.png)

When I try to update it, the building returns this message

`Build cache will not be stored because both the Node.js version and package manager version could not be determined. For more details see: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/troubleshoot-a-build#caching-process`

[Build cache will not be stored because both the Node.js version and package manager version could not be determined]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/43yt6.png)

And finally, when I try to check its logs, i can see just these warning messages, without any better indication:

[empty warning messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVezJ.png)

The result is that my site is only returning a 404 message

[404 - not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYEi3.png)

I'm not from back-end, or devops, so i really don't know what to do. Any tips?

Ps.: I'm doing this project based in [this course](https://www.udemy.com/course/do-zero-ao-fullstack/), and the [github project is here](https://github.com/Fernandomn/zero-to-fullstack-my-portfolio)

I already tried to read documentation about 404 and cache errors, but there's nothing that helps me. Also, looks like Vercel is really attached to project's framework, but i'm using only node.js and react

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.